# atomics/mutex hybrid counter

Tags: c++11, atomic, race-condition

I know that using atomics is dangerous (I watched Herb Sutter's 3hr lecture a few days ago), but the following use case seems reasonable to me, in terms of being simple and well contained.

**Questions:** (a) Is there something wrong with this? (Surely, there must be.) (b) Is there a name for this kind of hybrid atomic/mutex based approach? (c) Is there a simpler way of achieving the same thing?

The goal is to have a thread-safe counter class which we can call `attempt_invalidation()` on, knowing that it will only set its `invalid` flag to `true` if the count is at zero.   There will be no other public methods on the class, but we will have a friend class specially designed to do RAII incrementing/decrementing of the counter.

```
 class hybrid_counter{
    friend class hybrid_counter_user; 

    bool                invalidated = false; 
    int                 counter_a = 0;  
    std::atomic_int     counter_b;
    std::mutex          mu;

    bool increment_safely(){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(mu);
        if ( !invalidated )
            counter_a++;
        return invalidated;
    };
    void increment_dangerously(){
        counter_b++;
    };
    void decrement(){
        counter_b--; 
    };
 public:
    bool attempt_invalidation(){  
        if(counter_a + counter_b == 0){ 
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(mu);
            if(counter_a + counter_b == 0)
                invalidated = true;
        }
        return invalidated;
    };
};
```

This is the friend class that knows how to use the counter correctly:

```
class hybrid_counter_user{
public:
    hybrid_counter_user(hybrid_counter& hc){
        if(hc.increment_safely() == false) // is not yet invalidated
           c = &hc;
        else
           c = nullptr;
    };
    ~hybrid_counter_user(){
        if(c)
            c->decrement();
    };
    hybrid_counter_user(hybrid_counter_user&& old){ 
        c = old.c;
        old.c = nullptr;
    }
    hybrid_counter_user(hybrid_counter_user& other){
        c = other.c;
        if(c)
           c->increment_dangerously();
    }
private:
    hybrid_counter* c;
};
```

Note that the copy constructor uses the fact that `hybrid_counter` remains valid while `other` is in scope and `other`'s destructor cannot be reordered with `increment_dangerously` because both involve the same atomic var.
The move constructor is simply transferring responsibility for decrementing.

Comment: `attempt_invalidation` reads `counter_a` unprotected. Calling it simultaneously with `increment_safely` would result in a race. It also reads `invalidated` unprotected: two calls to `attempt_invalidation` race on that.

Comment: "I know that using atomics is dangerous (I watched Herb Sutter's 3hr lecture a few days ago)" - I didn't realise Herb had branched out into reactors.....

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - `attempt_invalidation` does read `counter_a` unprotected, but only so as to get a "heads up" as to whether it's likely to be worth while getting protection...inside the protected scope it doesn't rely on the outcome of the unprotected read.
And regarding the race on `invalidated`: firstly, I'm planning on only calling `attempt_invalidation` from a single "master" thread; and secondly, isn't the race benign because the flag can only ever be set to `true`, and it doesnt matter who accomplishes that so long as the count is zero?

Comment: Perhaps my requirements can be better met by a combination of `std::weak_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: A data race exhibits undefined behavior, no matter how righteous the justification. The value you read may legitimately be random garbage (e.g. due to a torn read), and so would decisions based on that value. [There ain't no such thing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) [as a "benign race"](http://hboehm.info/boehm-hotpar11.pdf) - all races exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: In addition to the data races noted above, `hybrid_counter::counter_b` is uninitialized.